# Drop Down List is not finding correct value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

When I connect my dropdownlist (cmbStaff) and then try and apply a selected value to cmbStaff it will always return the very first value within the dropdownlist.
Here is the code I use to bind data to the dropdownlist

```
 if(!IsPostBack)
{
    String Sql = @" select * from SupportTeam";

 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Resources.cString);
 SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(Sql, Properties.Resources.cString);
 DataSet DS = new DataSet();
 DA.Fill(DS, "SupportTeam");

 cmbStaff.DataValueField = "SupportTeamID";
 cmbStaff.DataTextField = "SupportTeamName";
 cmbStaff.DataSource = DS;
 cmbStaff.DataBind();
 cmbStaff.Items.Insert(0, "--Please select a support team--");
}
```

But in future code when I try and apply a selected value to the drop down it will always select the first index.

For example, if I do this

```
cmbStaff.SelectedValue = "TEL";
```

When I debug, it will always return this

```
cmbStaff.SelectedValue = "--Please select a support team--"
cmbStaff.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Why is it doing this.
I have data stored in the table as the combo works it just does not set starting index to the value that I want and that is what I need it to do.

Here is a snippet of the data I have stored in the SupportTeam Table
[image]

Sorry if is seem vague, thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want to programmatically change the selected value in your combobox? Or was it just an example?

Comment: Your problem is not clear. But you should set `datasource` before setting    `DataValueField` and `DataTextField` to `dropdownlist`

Comment: Its always best to set the datasource last in my opinion, works either way and doesn't affect the code.  Thanks anyway for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was having was Sql Related.  It keep adding blank spaces onto the end of the value I was entering. I changed

```
String Sql = @" select * from SupportTeam";
```

to

```
String Sql = @" select rtrim(SupportTeamID) as SupportTeamID, rtrim(SupportTeamName) as SupportTeamName from SupportTeam";
```

It now works.  I cannot find the exact reason why this happened.  Of course the .Trim() function will also work when declaring Sql variables in c#.

Answer (score 1):

That is not how you set a selected value for a drop down list. you use the findbyvalue function and set selected =true

```
cmbStaff.Items.FindByValue("TEL").Selected = true;
```

Comment: .SelectedValue works fine, I would use your way for search functions.  It was my Sql code that was playing up but thanks anyway!